# sudo over ssh - stuck when password is not accepted

Tags: ssh, sudo

To check, if user does have sudo (on multiple server at once), I'm using following command:
`echo -e "$Password" | ssh -tt -q $Username@$Server "sudo -S -p '' echo ok" 2>&1`
This approach seems to work, but only if the password is accepted. If you are (for whatever reason) asked for the password again, the command hangs, and the whole script with it.
Is there a way to force this command to end, if the password is not accepted?

Answer (score 3):

The command is not hanging.  It is waiting.

You have specified that the `sudo` command should read the password from stdin (`-S`) and not prompt the user to enter a password (`-p ''`).  If you enter the wrong password, `sudo` will wait for you to try again -- by default, three times.

I cannot find any option to `sudo` -- either on the command line or in the `sudo.conf` config file -- that will allow you to ask only once for the password and then exit.